# Move a figure a bit left

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to insert a pdf figure in a beamer presentation. I'm using

```
\begin{frame}{foo}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{bar}
\end{frame}
```

The figure is always placed a bit too much to the right. How can I move the figure a bit to the left? A quick & dirty solution is acceptable here.

Comment: If the figure is placed too much on the right, are you sure it is not too big for your slide, given the margins on a frame? `beamer` should left align images as far as I know, so when it appears as placed too much to the right, it might just be sticking in the margin.

Comment: Do you want to move the figure to the left or to the right?

Answer (score 33):

Try `\hspace{-0.5em}` before the `\includegraphics`.  You may need to put them in an `\hbox.` So:

```
\begin{frame}{foo}
\hbox{\hspace{-0.5em} \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{bar}}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: For example, in my case, `\hbox{\hspace{26ex}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{aPicture.pdf}}`

Comment: Actually, it can also work without a \frame context

Answer (score 11):

As Pieter comments, it sounds like the figure is too large to fit in the measure of your document. In which case, centring on a single line might work so it overhangs to both sides:

```
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{bar}}
```

Note that `\centerline` is really only recommended for cases like this; it will only ever typeset its contents in a single line, so generally `\centering` is the preferred option.

Comment: if picture is to big, than probably will help `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{bar}`.

Comment: @Zarko — but what if that's still too small? My solution is intended for the case that you want the image to be larger than the textwidth.

Comment: than you should look for `changepage` package. see my answer below.

Comment: @Zarko — yes, I'm aware of that package (check its maintainer). But that's suboptimal in this case; besides all the extra markup required you have to hard code `{-0.5cm}{-0.5cm}` as part of the placement, when with `\centerline` you automatically spill out on both sides of the text block.

Comment: sorry for trying to teach you about this package :-) (next time I should check packages authors and maintainers ...) . About hard code of image size: in your case it is hidden in `includegraphics` option `scale`. It should be appropriate adjusted otherwise the image can become bigger than frame. In my suggestion the first is determined image space and than the image width is automatically adjusted to it.

Answer (score 4):

See, if this is helpful:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}{foo}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-0.5cm}{-0.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=7cm]{example-image}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Rule above image indicate text width.