# How to shift position of only one of the (imported) pictures that are side-by-side?

Tags: beamer, graphics

I am trying to include two following pictures side-by-side into `beamer`:

[image][image]

but usually the second is placed lower than the first one. It depends on their sizes:

- if I want them to be of a similarly size then their horizontal axes are not the same.
- if I make their horizontal axes to be the same, then the second picture has to bigger than the first one.

I have used `\includegraphics`, `\subfigure`, `\mbox` and similar commands, but it somehow does not have any effect.

I have tried also this: [Move a figure a bit right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4434/move-a-figure-a-bit-right)

Maybe the reason is that the pictures have different resolutions?

Thanks for advice.

Edit: The first image may cause the problems: opening it in "Eye of GNOME 2.30.0" one gets this view:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use `\includegraphics` inside a `tabular` environement? EDIT: What about this: `\begin{frame} \frametitle{Title} \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth} \begin{minipage}[c]{0.49\textwidth} \begin{center} \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1}\\ Caption1 \end{center} \end{minipage} \begin{minipage}[c]{0.49\textwidth} \begin{center} \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig2}\\ Caption 2 \end{center} \end{minipage} \end{minipage} \end{frame}`

Comment: Yes, and the problem is still the same:(

Comment: The standard answer should be to say `\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[...]{...}}`; the `adjustbox` package provides more tools.

Comment: @egreg Thank you, this works well. It is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (maybe too) simplistic solution is to say

```
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[...]{...}}
```

The package `adjustbox` provides many other tools.

Answer (score 5):

There are of course several approaches here. I'd use [`xcoffins`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcoffins)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\NewCoffin{\CoffinA}
\NewCoffin{\CoffinB}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \SetHorizontalCoffin{\CoffinA}{\includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{iDd8t}}%
  \SetHorizontalCoffin{\CoffinB}{\includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{WtVfE}}%
  \JoinCoffins{\CoffinA}[vc,r]{\CoffinB}[vc,l]%
  \TypesetCoffin{\CoffinA}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

If you want to do a manual shift, you just need to use a line of the form

```
\JoinCoffins{\CoffinA}[vc,r]{\CoffinB}[vc,l](0 pt, 0pt)
```

where the two dimensions are the horizontal and vertical shift of the second image, respectively.

Comment: I've used the images as-uploaded, by the way.